# azure function queueTrigger error - Microsoft Azure WebJobs SDK '[Hidden Credential]' connection string is missing or empty

Tags: c#, azure, queue, azure-web-app-service, azure-functions

I have created new `Azure Function` for `QueueTrigger` but after running it locally getting some weird error below.

Function1.cs

```
public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static void Run([QueueTrigger("demoqueue", Connection = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=myconnectionstring")]string myQueueItem, TraceWriter log)
        {
            log.Info($"C# Queue trigger function processed: {myQueueItem}");
        }
    }
```

local.setting.json

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
        "AzureWebJobsDashboard": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true"
    }
}
```

Error -

> [11/14/2018 4:36:15 PM] The following 1 functions are in error:
>   [11/14/2018 4:36:15 PM] Run: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error
>   indexing method 'Function1.Run'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host:
>   Microsoft Azure WebJobs SDK '[Hidden Credential]' connection string is
>   missing or empty. The Microsoft Azure Storage account connection
>   string can be set in the following ways: [11/14/2018 4:36:15 PM] 1.
>   Set the connection string named '[Hidden Credential]' in the
>   connectionStrings section of the .config file in the following format
>   , or [11/14/2018 4:36:15 PM] 2. Set the environment variable named
>   '[Hidden Credential]', or [11/14/2018 4:36:15 PM] 3. Set corresponding
>   property of JobHostConfiguration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify the key of the app setting where your connection string is stored in the config not the connectionstring itself.

```
public static void Run([QueueTrigger("demoqueue", Connection = "NameOfYourAppSetting")]
```

Comment: Thanks man, stupid me was trying to add the connection string there.